# Does the Rust actors framework Actix guarantee message order between two actors?

Tags: rust, actor, rust-actix

In the case of one single actor sending a message to another single actor.

I couldn't find anything about this in the official documentation.

Comment: Note: if you have not already, I suggest asking on the r/rust reddit channel, where the author of the framework is quite active. If you do so, please be sure to cross-reference with this question.

Comment: @GustavoBasso If you get an answer there, don't forget to come back here and answer your own question in case someone else would ever have the same!

Answer (score 8):

The order in which messages are received from one single actor to another single actor is deterministic:

> Order is deterministic. Actix uses mpsc queue for messages

See the [answer from the author in the rust subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/8bhp4s/does_actix_rust_actors_framework_guarantee/dx6sqa3/).